MS-Outlook 365 OLE Sort Problems
I've recently had the problem with Outlook 365 that I no longer receive certain fields such as the subject back after sorting.
Does anyone have a similar problem?
Example:
Sort "[ReceivedTime]"
Best regards
Bernd
I've tried all sorting methods, always the same, the whole thing runs under Windows 11, it must be a combination of Windows 11, Outlook and one of the latest fix packs because it ran smoothly until a while ago!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
